# C++ FL Studio SDK how to listen generator events

Tags: c++, plugins, midi, vst

I want to create custom VST plugin but before I want to know:

How to listen any event related to some of generators in FL Studio?

Is it possible to get current/active generator window id/name while swapping them in FL Studio? Also to get name and value of any control (knob, fade e.t.c.)

[image]

Should I use [FL Studio SDK](https://forum.image-line.com/viewtopic.php?f=700&t=12092) or [WDL-OL](https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol) C++ library? Still can't find any reliable info about this issue.

Comment: Those are internal states of FL so you need their SDK. VST doesn't cover that. I cannot get more specific as I have not programmed in/with FL's SDK. For Steinberg DAWs/products they have a separate SKI (Steinberg Kernel Interface) api that does kind of stuff. It's not handled through VST. Oh, and SKI is not public; it requires NDA signature.